# Update Values in a List with Values from Another List

Tags: apex, list, loop

I want to update the values of records in a list with the values in another list.

I keep getting this error:

> Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a
>   concrete SObject: String

`contactlist` is a contacts list.

`accountidlist` is a string list.

Do both lists have to be of the same type? What am I missing here?

```
for(Contact j : contactlist) {
    for(String l : accountidlist){
       j.Account = l.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **contactlist is a contacts list.**

AND **accountidlist is a string list.**

then code should be like

```
for(Contact j : contactlist) {
    for(String l : accountidlist){
       j.AccountId = l;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it, I see my error. I appreciate your help sfdcweb.